# Non partition to partitioned Bigquery table DBT model without overwriting partition

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I am trying to create a dbt model (Bigquery Database) which will fetch data from a non partitioned table (Table A) and insert in a partitioned table (Table B).

Table A has a date column which should define which partition the data should go into Table B. Table B might have those partition as existing or those might be new partition. Table A will have data for multiple days and hence identifying which partition to overwrite is not possible beforehand.

I have tried the **insert_overwrite incremental strategy** , but this is replacing the data for the existing partition which is not expected. I want to insert data in specific partition based on Table A and not overwrite anything. Is **merge** strategy the right option or there is any other solution for this ?